# $G$-CW complex structure of universal a $\mathcal{F}$-space

Tags: equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be an abelian subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of all subgroups of $H$ , i.e. $\mathcal{F}= \{K : K \leq H\}$ Define universal $\mathcal{F}$-space $E\mathcal{F}$ as in Peter May's Alaska Notes.

Question 1: What is $G$-CW complex structure of $E\mathcal{F}$ ?

Question 2: Is the $n$-th skeleton of $E\mathcal{F}$ is $G$-homotopy equivalence with $G/H \ast G/H \ast \cdots \ast G/H$ (n+1 topological join)?

Any hint or reference will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your family $\mathcal{F}$ is not closed under conjugation if $H$ is not normal. Depending on what you want to do, this may not be an issue.

There are two references for the construction of $E\mathcal{F}$ that I know of (but I would be glad to hear of more). The first is tom Dieck's book *Transformation groups*, where in Chapter I.6 he states that a model for $E\mathcal{F}$ is given by the infinite join 
$$
E\mathcal{F} = X \ast X \ast \cdots
$$
where $X=\bigsqcup G/H_a$ is a disjoint union of orbit types. This is a $G$-CW complex in an obvious way, and suggests that the answer to your second question is no.

The second reference is Lück's *Transformation groups and algebraic $K$-theory*, available from [the author's webpage](https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/publications.php) (scroll down to Books). Apparently, using the results in Chapter 2 of that book, one can build a $G$-CW complex model for $E\mathcal{F}$ by an iterative process of attaching $G$-cells. The construction is not carried out explicitly, however, and I'm not sure of the details (perhaps this is the topic for a separate MO question).

Comment: Actually I'm interested to calculate integer graded Bredon cohomology of $ X = G/H \ast G/H \ast \cdots \ast G/H$ with constant coefficient system , which is equivalent to calculated the cohomology of $X/G.$ For this reason , I need $G$-CW complex structure of $X.$ How can I proceed ? Any hint?

Comment: The action of $G$ on your space $X$ is not free (its isotropy groups are all conjugates of $H$) so I don't see why the Bredon cohomology should reduce to the ordinary cohomology of the quotient.

Comment: Because I have taken constant coefficient system.

Comment: Ah, OK. Maybe it would be better to ask a separate question about Bredon cohomology of joins. Before doing so, you could think about how this relates to the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211122/k%C3%BCnneth-formula-for-bredon-cohomology-theory given that $Y\ast Z\simeq \Sigma Y\wedge Z$.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the post is worth bumping (and editing) just for this, but here is a working link: https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/publications.php (and a link [directly to the book](https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/data/lueck_Transformation_Groups_and_Algebraic_K-theory.pdf))

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks, I fixed the broken link.